# Control M job appears in Planning but not in Monitoring

Tags: control-m

I have created a Control-M job, validated it and checked in. I see it in the Planning-Home tab, but not in the Monitoring tab. Basically, I need to run this job using the "Run now" option. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you order the job  ? Only  ordered jobs you can see in Monitoring window..
you can see these jobs after new day if your frequency set other  than "Manual order"

Hope it resolves
Sachin

Answer (score 0):

Think of Planning vs Monitoring as class definition vs class object instance. In planning you define your job; in monitoring you initialize instances of the job. The job may be auto-instantiated by the PUDLY/auto/daemon process based on  job schedule specified in Planning. Otherwise, you may order up an instance of your job disregarding scheduling requirements using the Order feature in Monitoring view.

Answer (score 0):

Control-M uses unusal wording "order a job to be run".

Jobs from Planning domain don't run until "ordered" which in the end means "copied from Planning into Monitoring domain". **Only then** these jobs are scheduled to run or executed manually.